# Event Handler function in prototype's method, why does it think .keyCode is a property of undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, constructor, event-handling

I am experimenting with DOM event handlers, and I put in my Constructor's prototype a function that works on the DOM div element, which is a property created by the constructor in my object. It displays the object correctly, but the only thing that does not work is that it thinks that in my method, `.keyCode`, is a property of undefined and gives me an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined (line 16 in function KeyBlock.move)

This is my method, along with my calling of it:

```
  KeyBlock.prototype.move = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37)
    this.x -= 1;
  if(event.keyCode == 38)
    this.y -= 1;
  if(event.keyCode == 39)
    this.x += 1;
  if(event.keyCode == 40)
    this.y += 1;
  if (this.y < 0)
    this.y = 0;
  if (this.x < 0)
    this.x = 0;
  console.log(this.y);
}
me = new KeyBlock("me");
addEventListener("keyup", me.move(event));
```

It might have to do with the argument, `event`, in the method? To answer this question, my constructor itself will not be needed, but I will also place it (below this text), to make clear what I am doing.

```
  var KeyBlock = function(name) {
  this.character = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(this.character);
  this.character.style.width = "20px";
  this.character.style.height = "20px";
  this.name = name;
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.character.style.background = "indigo";
  this.character.id = this.name;
  this.character.style.left = String(this.x) + "px";
  this.character.style.top = String(this.y) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're **calling** your method(with a not defined `event` argument) in your `addEventListener` call instead of **passing** it.

`addEventListener("keyup", me.move(event));`

should be

`addEventListener("keyup", me.move);`

to have access to your `this` property you need to `bind` the function aswell:

`addEventListener("keyup", KeyBlock.prototype.move.bind(me));`

Comment: this still doesn't update my `this.character.style.left` or `.top`, but it does update my `this.x` and `this.y`, would that be because it took my original `this.x` and `this.y` as constants and will not update them to the other properties? If so, how do I fix that problem?

Comment: You're building a CSS value string out of your `this.x` and you need to do it again when this.x changes. Please mark this answer as correct and do not ask new questions in the comments, create a *new question* for a *new problem* or figure it out.