# My DOM object will not update after my data updates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, methods

I have this square, created with a constructor, and all my data does update, including its .style.top and .style.left, but it will not update on the page (the picture). Here is my code, i am omitting the constructor itself because it is probably not the problem. I have included the the method of the constructor and the call of the method, which doesn't update the picture.

```
  KeyBlock.prototype.move = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 37)
    this.x -= 10;
  if(event.keyCode == 38)
    this.y -= 10;
  if(event.keyCode == 39)
    this.x += 10;
  if(event.keyCode == 40)
    this.y += 10;
  if (this.y < 0)
    this.y = 0;
  if (this.x < 0)
    this.x = 0;
  this.character.style.left = String(this.x) + "px";
  this.character.style.top = String(this.y) + "px";
  console.log(this.character.style.left);
}

me = new KeyBlock("me");
addEventListener("keyup", KeyBlock.prototype.move.bind(me));
```

If you want to see the constructor, it is available at this question, but it probably is not needed to answer the question: [Event Handler function in prototype's method, why does it think .keyCode is a property of undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681939/event-handler-function-in-prototypes-method-why-does-it-think-keycode-is-a-pr)

thanks ahead of time :)

Comment: What is `this.character` in your code?

Comment: @jfriend00, this.character is defined in the original Constructor, it is the property that holds the div object, you can access the code for the constructor in my link in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in the code you show either in this question or in the linked constructor do you give your character a `position` style value.  In order for `style.left` and `style.top` to do anything, you must set the `style.position` value to something other than the default of `static`.

---

FYI, you don't need to manually convert things to strings when you are adding a number to a string (the number will be auto-coverted).  So instead of this:

```
this.character.style.left = String(this.x) + "px";
```

You can just do this:

```
this.character.style.left = this.x + "px";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @jfriend00, I forgot about that step